# Не запускается chromedriver selenium python на VPS

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium, chromedriver

На VPS стоит Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Запускаю такой код:

```
from selenium import webdriver


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

И получаю ошибку: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127`

chromedriver добавлен в PATH, версия `92.0.4515.43`.
Установлена стабильная версия (92) Chrome

Comment: ubuntu server или desktop?

Comment: @Violet desktop

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте прописать явно путь к папке с `chromedriver` и добавить ее через `executable_path`. В моем случае я добавил `chromedriver` в текущую рабочую папку.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

executable_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'chromedriver')
print(executable_path)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=executable_path)
```